# Full background youtube video - fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, fullpage.js

How to set up full background youtube video in fullpage.js section ? fullPage.js provide example using `<video>` tag, but I want to use youtube video, so I must use `<iframe>` tag. This [pen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd) helped me, but it doesn't work well with fullPage.js `responsiveWidth` property. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use some CSS to make the iframe fit the whole page then add this code to everything else in CSS.
`position: relative;
z-index: 2;`

Note 1: change position to any value if you need to, the z-index will still be working
Note 2: if you have a way to select elements that doesn't have a class, use it for this purpose. I know `:not(.testclass) { }` But it's not supported in IE, if you got another way, use it.

Edit: I just realized that the control buttons on the bottom of the video will be shown, Try editing the size and position to hide them from the visitors.